# Django admin change plural model names

Tags: django, django-admin

My Django (Grappelli theme) admin lists all my apps and then the model names are displayed in plural form. To convert the name to plural, Django adds an 's' to the name of the model, however some of these are incorrect.  For example, 'Product categories' becomes 'Product categorys'

**How can I change the names displayed in the admin views for these?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to specify a `verbose_name_plural` attribute in your model's `Meta` subclass.

Check: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.verbose_name_plural for more info.

Comment: For 1.9 this link works for verbose_name_plural: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#verbose-name-plural